The topology on varieties and schemes induced by the frame of subsheaves in the Zariski topos
Since the precise question I want to ask takes a lot of set up, let me start with a vague question.
Question (version 0).
If we consider the Zariski subsheaves of a scheme to be the open subspaces of some other space, what is that space?
Is it related to the constructible topology?

Let $k$ be a (commutative) ring.
Every $k$-scheme $X$ can be considered as a functor $\textbf{CAlg}_k \to \textbf{Set}$:
$$X (A) = \{ k\text{-morphisms} \operatorname{Spec} A \to X \}$$
Suppose we try to topologise $X (A)$ by declaring that a subset is open if and only if the subset is the image of the map $X' (A) \to X (A)$ induced by some $k$-scheme morphism $X' \to X$.
Then certainly we have closure under finitary intersections, but unions are problematic.
This can be resolved by requiring $A$ to be a local $k$-algebra.
We might also worry about whether the topology is too fine – indeed, if $k$ is a field, then $X (k)$ is discrete – so let us also add the restriction that the morphism $X' \to X$ be locally of finite presentation.
It is a bit of a hassle to carry around $A$ and $k$, so we could try to combine the $X (A)$ together.
With a bit of work, it can be shown that the set $X_\textrm{pt}$ of points of the "underlying" topological space of $X$ is the colimit of $X (k')$ as $k'$ varies over the fields over $k$.
Since the topology on $X (A)$ defined above is functorial in $A$, we obtain an induced topology on $X_\textrm{pt}$.
Open immersions are locally of finite presentation, so it is clear that the induced topology on $X_\textrm{pt}$ is finer than the Zariski topology.
In the case where $X$ is noetherian, even Zariski-closed subsets become open in the new topology, but in general we can only conclude that the images of morphisms locally of finite presentation are open.
Question (version 1).
Does the topology on $X_\textrm{pt}$ defined above coincide with the constructible topology for some reasonable class of schemes $X$?
If not, is it at least comparable (finer/coarser)?

Now let me explain what I am actually interested in.
Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the category of functors $F : \textbf{CAlg}_k \to \textbf{Set}$  that satisfy the following conditions:

$F (\{ 0 \}) \cong 1$.

For all $k$-algebras $A$ and all $a \in A$, the following is a pullback square:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F (A) @>>> F (A [a^{-1}]) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
F (A [(1 - a)^{-1}]) @>>> F (A [a^{-1}, (1 - a)^{-1}])
\end{CD}$$

$F$ preserves colimits of small filtered diagrams.


Though it is not immediate from the definition above, $\mathcal{E}$ is a Grothendieck topos: the first two conditions are equivalent to the Zariski sheaf condition, and the third condition ensures that there is a small generating set.
In fact, the third condition makes $\mathcal{E}$ the classifying topos for local $k$-algebras.
Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a Grothendieck topos, the (preordered) collection of all subobjects of an object is (equivalent to) a frame, i.e. a complete lattice in which arbitrary joins distribute over finitary meets.
On the other hand, the functor of points of a $k$-scheme satisfies the third condition above if it is locally of finite presentation.
Question (version 2).
What is the locale corresponding to the frame of subobjects of a $k$-scheme locally of finite presentation, considered as an object in $\mathcal{E}$?
Conceptually, $\mathcal{E}$ is the category of all sets constructible from a variable local $k$-algebra $O$: this is basically what it means to be the classifying topos for local $k$-algebras.
For example, given $O$, we can certainly construct the set of elements of $O$: this is  $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.
Likewise, we can construct the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $O$: this is $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.
Or we could construct the set of pairs $(x_0, x_1)$ such that $a_0 x_0 + a_1 x_1 = 1$ for some pair $(a_0, a_1)$ (this is $\mathbb{A}^2_k \setminus \{ 0 \}$) and then quotient by the equivalence relation identifying $(x_0, x_1)$ with $(x_2, x_3)$ iff $x_0 x_3 = x_1 x_2$ (this is $\mathbb{P}^1_k$).
And so on – everything in $\mathcal{E}$ can be constructed from $O$ using (iterated) finite limits and small colimits, i.e. the operations that are defined in any Grothendieck topos and are preserved by the inverse image functor of any geometric morphism.
In terms of the construction of subsets, this basically means we can form the subset of all elements satisfying logical formulae built using $=$, $\land$ (finitary conjunction), $\bigvee$ (arbitrary disjunction), and $\exists$.
In particular, the availability of $=$ basically why (some) Zariski-closed subsets can be constructed, whereas it is $\exists$ and $\bigvee$ that gives us Zariski-open subsets.
(For example, $\mathbb{A}^1_k \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is the subset $\{ x \in O : \exists y \in O . x y = 1 \}$.)
But all this talk of "constructible" is in the sense of logic; is it related to "constructible" in the sense of Chevalley's theorem?
There is an additional subtlety: in the above I talked as if we have actual sets and actual elements, but a priori we do not.
Fortunately, $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos with enough points, so this is not too harmful if we are careful.
For example,
$$F = \{ x \in O : x = 0 \lor \exists y \in O . x y = 1 \}$$
defines a proper subset of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ even though it satisfies $F (k') = \mathbb{A}^1_k (k')$ for all fields $k'$ over $k$; we can only distinguish between $F$ and $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ by instantiating with local $k$-algebras.
Yet, we only consider fields when defining $X_\textrm{pt}$, so we are losing some fidelity when passing from subobjects of $X$ to subsets of $X_\textrm{pt}$.
The locale defined in the question above is therefore distinct from the topological space defined earlier, but is it very different?
